# Typescript and value can't be null

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator, null-check

I have a typescript code as follows:

```
  constructor(c?: IContact) {
    this.id = c ? c.id : null;
    this.caseId = c ? c.caseId : null;
    this.name = c ? c.name : '';
    this.email = c ? c.email : '';
    this.isPrimary = c ? c.isPrimary : false;
  }
```

What does the 'c ?' do? And how do I ensure when the user enter the contact the c.email is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` and `:` is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It takes on the form `condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`. So, `true ? "foo" : "bar"` would be `"foo"`, whereas `false ? "foo" : "bar"` would be `"bar"`.

Note that the condition is not restricted to booleans: it can be any value, and the condition is evaluated based on the [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) of the value. An important falsy value is `null` and `undefined`.

So, `c ? c.email : ''` means that if `c` is null or undefined, then default to `''` for the email, otherwise use `c.email` for the email.

If you want to ensure `c.email` isn't null, then you can add a check:

```js
this.email = c ? c.email : '';
if (this.email === null) {
    throw new ValueError("Email cannot be null.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `c ? c.A : null` ensures that c is not undefined before it attempts to access its attribute. Since your input is optional (`(c?: IContact)`), you would need that check.

Here is the code to ensure `c.email` is not null -

```
  constructor(c?: IContact) {
    this.id = c ? c.id : null;
    this.caseId = c ? c.caseId : null;
    this.name = c ? c.name : '';
    this.email = c ? (c.email || '') : '';
    this.isPrimary = c ? c.isPrimary : false;
  }
```

You can replace the `||` with a `??`. Works the same.